# How to get "Who to follow" users from Twitter api?

Tags: php, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I know there do exist a couple questions with this title. But the only answer I'm finding was to use twitter's `users/suggestions` solution. That however returns me a list of slugs and if I then do `users/suggestions/:slug/members` I get a list of users that are related to that topic but they are usually top rated, which is not what I want. I want random people, not split into random categories, but picked up by twitter's own algorithm like this:

[image]

If there is a way to achieve this, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

PS: Sorry for the first user suggestion. It just happened. xd

Answer (score 1):

There's no API available from Twitter to do this.

Comment: Yeah I realised that later. However I'd like to know something similar to twitter's algorithm to show me relevant users using the api. I realised it was possible to get the followers and friends of a given user with the api, and therefore it could also be possible to form a list with users